# Managing changes to Scala immutable state from a scheduled task

Tags: scala, state, immutability

I have an immutable object graph in Scala (mostly immutable - read on). Somewhere deep down in my graph is an object representing a cache. The cache contains a `ScheduledExecutorService` that periodically makes calls to an external system and updates the contents of the cache.

My question is: if I want my cache to be truly immutable, it needs to reconstruct itself whenever there is a change, but how does this work if there are no vars to update and no "caller" to which I can return a modified cache?

The examples I've seen of patterns like the state monad are all driven by a caller on a single thread, so it's trivial to just return a modified state object (the cache) to the caller. This would work fine for me if I only wanted to update the cache contents when someone queries it. But the update operation is expensive and it's far preferable to do it in the background and swap out the cache contents once it's done.

Comment: A cache is by definition not friendly to being made immutable, as it's primary purpose is to hold temporary data. And since a cache is basically an optimization, copying the cache is likely self-defeating. A monad helps you sequence state changes without using temporary variables -- it doesnt solve this problem.

Comment: In my case the data being cached is just a Seq. It's cheap to copy the cache, but expensive to update over the network.I suspect that I could pull the scheduled task out of the cache and have some top-level object with an executor driving everything and feeding "new" cache objects to the rest of my graph when changes are detected, but I have no idea if this is considered the best way of doing what I want or if maybe there's some existing pattern in FP-land that people follow already to maintain this immutability.

Comment: The other property of a cache is that its contents are generally reproducible. A cache miss and a cache hit should result in the same value, with cost being the variable. It sounds like having to go to the network is your "cache miss" scenario. Im probably misunderstanding but it seems like you may be prematurely updating some cache elements (i.e. copying the whole seq around when you only need the element youre currently accessing).

Comment: You could look at vector clocks; storing a clock with each element, and then you would know if the element you're accessing is out of date or not. There are databases that already do this though - may be best to use one of them -- or one of the various cache libraries out there.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work to pass the cache around as an implicit context? Like

```
trait Cache[A] {
  def apply(): A
}

trait Immutable {
  def foo(implicit resolver: Cache[Int]): Any
}
```

?